# Setting up a matlab program for oppositely ordering two vectors

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 50x3 matrix and would like to oppositely order the first column to the sum of the other two columns. i.e. Say we have columns A,B,and C. Taking A, i sum B and C. so that i have two columns(50x2). Next, working with the 50x2 matrix I want to rearrange A such that it becomes oppositely ordered to the second column(which was gotten from adding B and C). Two vectors a,b are oppositely ordered if

```
(a_j - a_k)(b_j - b_k) ≤ 0 , ∀ 1≤j,k≤N  Where N=50,j=2.
```

For example
X =
  [15.2221,49.0000,12.3631; 20.3201,22.5702,30.6228; 12.1306,9.4257,10.3228; 16.1499,21.3606,11.5000; 16.6777,30.6228,13.4338]

using the first column, take the sum of the other two columns. so we have a new matrix
Y =
   [15.2221,61.3631; 20.3201,53.1930; 12.1306,19.7485; 16.1499,32.8606; 16.6777,44.0565]

Rearrange the only the first column such that

(y11-y12)(y21-y22) <= 0
y11-y13)(y21-y23) <= 0, e.t.c

In the end we have a new matrix Y where the first column is rearranged while the second column remains the same. eg

Y = 
   [15.2221,61.3631; 16.1499,53.1930; 20.3201,19.7485; 16.6777,32.8606; 12.1306,44.0565]

I hope you understand my explanations. I want to import what I've done on matlab thus far, but i'm still learning the basics.

Comment: Have you tried using `sort`? Post what you have tried...

Comment: Miriam, we can probably help you if you post a simple and clear example of your starting situation and step-wise what you want Matlab to do. Please post it with ~5x3 matrix, not 50x3 :)

Comment: Please consider visiting http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works. You should consider posting what have you tried so far.

Comment: OMG. I edited your post 50 minutes ago to the correct format and now it is the wrong format again....

Answer (score 0):

So first, you want your 2 by 50 matrix:

```
X =
   [15.2221   49.0000   12.3631;
    20.3201   22.5702   30.6228;
    12.1306   9.4257    10.3228;
    16.1499   21.3606   11.5000;
    16.6777   30.6228   13.4338]

Xtransform = [X(:,1),(X(:,2)+X(:,3))]; %//This generates 2 by 50 Matrix
```

Next you want to re-order your first column such that (y11-y12)(y21-y22) <= 0 (based on my understanding), so a bit of math on that:

you want the all possible combinations of v1 and v2 to construct the function:

```
  C1 = nchoosek(v1,2);
  C2 = nchoosek(v2,2);

  %//Do y11-y12 
  CC1 = C1(:,1) - C1(:,2);
  %//Consider backwards
  CB1 = C1(:,2) - C1(:,1);
  %//Do y21-y22
  CC2 = C2(:,1) - C2(:,2); 
  %//Consider backwards
  CB2 = C2(:,2) - C2(:,1);
  %//CC1 *CC2 should return negative or zero
  CC = find(CC1.*CC2 < 0);
  CB = find(CB1.*CC2 < 0);
  %//The indexes returned are possible v1 and v2 combinations that fullfills the required function.
```

So I got to this point, and wondered what if the question can be fullfilled with multiple solutions. If there are multiple ordering that fullfills the function, what should be the correct way to order it?

With the indexes at hand, you could look at C1 and C2 to see which ajk and bjk values fullfill the function.

Comment: Please @qmeeeeeee what is defined by v1 and v2

Comment: please guys i'm still in need of your suggestions. Thank you